# How to implement circular menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, circular-dependency

I started customizing circular widget on my android application. i got something similar to my requirements by converting recycler view into a curved shape. but the problem is multiple layers are overlapping each other. how to make layers independently clickable. please help me out. Thanks in advance.

[look at this This is how recycler views are overlapping each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2iWY.png)

[the expected design looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAuFw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your drawable file. it will be make right curve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="150dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
i am able to set the background drawable, t's not the problem.
when i try to scroll at the corner, the top recyclerview is getting scrolled not the second one. i am just wondering, how can we stop the touch events getting triggered. on that area.